# Enter triggers submit on master page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my master page there is a submit button for the site search. On most pages this is only triggered if enter is hit whilst the search box has focus. On a couple of pages though hitting enter on the main form it triggers the search submit.

I know that I could fix this by enclosing the search in it's own form tag and then changing every page to have it's own form tag, but I need something that is a lot simpler as a fix as I'm low on time. Is there a way I can tie the text boxes in the form to the correct submit button?

I can post code if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter will result in the first-found submit button on the page being pressed.

Wrap your 'forms' into a Panel:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlForm1" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmit"/>
</asp:Panel>
```